Hibernate pooling warnings that I don't know how to resolve
When I run spring boot locally, org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling logs out a bunch of undefined values.
Can anyone give me the properties key to resolve those undefined values. I tried out a lot but nothing works. I'm using Spring Boot 3 with Hibernate 6
app-1  | 2024-09-30T16:50:19.798Z  INFO 162 --- [ExpenseTracker] [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001005: Database info:
app-1  |        Database JDBC URL [Connecting through datasource 'HikariDataSource (HikariPool-11)']
app-1  |        Database driver: undefined/unknown
app-1  |        Database version: 8.0.39
app-1  |        Autocommit mode: undefined/unknown
app-1  |        Isolation level: undefined/unknown
app-1  |        Minimum pool size: undefined/unknown
app-1  |        Maximum pool size: undefined/unknown


Ignore it you don't need those, those are set through the datasource and not through Hibernate. Hence hibernate doesn't know these.
